# The add method in a CakePHP Controller doesn't work

Tags: cakephp, addition, cakephp-2.4

When I am trying to include new content, in this controller, he's not running the save option and returns the error message, since I used the print_r function to check the $ this-> request-> data, and is passing the correct parameters. below is the code:

Controller/CanvasController.php:

```
class CanvasController extends AppController {
    public $name = 'Canvas';
    function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        //$this -> layout = 'dialog';
        $this -> layout = 'default-original';
    }

    public function index() {
        $this -> set('Canvas', $this -> Canvas -> find('all'));
    }

    public function add() {
        if ($this -> request -> is('post')) {
            if ($this -> Canvas -> save($this -> request -> data)) {
                $this -> Session -> setFlash(__('The Canvas has been saved'));
                $this -> redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this -> Session -> setFlash(__('The Canvas could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
    }

    public function edit($id = null) {
        $this -> Canvas -> id = $id;
        if ($this -> request -> is('get')) {
            $this -> request -> data = $this -> Canvas -> read();
        } else if ($this -> Canvas -> save($this -> request -> data)) {
            $this -> Session -> setFlash('Canvas updated.');
            $this -> redirect(array('controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'index'));
        }
    }

    public function delete($id = null) {
        if (!$this -> request -> is('post')) {
            throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
        }
        $this -> Canvas -> id = $id;
        if (!$this -> Canvas -> exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid.'));
        }
        if ($this -> Canvas -> delete($id)) {
            $this -> Session -> setFlash('The Canvas with id: ' . $id . ' has been deleted.');
            $this -> redirect(array('controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this -> Session -> setFlash(__('Canvas was deleted.'));
        $this -> redirect(array('controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

Model/Canvas.php:

```
class Canvas extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Canvas';

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'users' => array(
            'classname' => 'Users',
            'foreignkey' => 'canvas_id',
            'joinTable' => 'canvas_has_users'
        )
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'CanvasContents' => array(
            'classname' => 'CanvasContents',
            'foreignKey' => 'canvas_id'
        )
    );

    public $validate = array(
        'name' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array(
                    'notEmpty'
                ),
                'message' => 'A name is required'
            )
        )
    );
}
```

View/Canvas/add.ctp:

```
<?php echo $this -> Form -> create('Canvas'); ?>
<fieldset>
    <?php   echo $this -> Form -> input('name'); ?>
    <?php   echo $this -> Form -> input('description'); ?>
</fieldset>
<?php   echo $this -> Form -> end('Submit');?>
```

SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sistema`.`canvas` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `description` TEXT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: What is the error message? Is it failing at validation? Does it fail at save/write time? (Is your DB up and running with the table existing and properly configured?)

Comment: In add function he is not going to$this -> Canvas -> save($this -> request -> data)

Comment: how can i get the error?

Comment: Why the spaces around the object operators (`->`)?

Comment: try `if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put')))`

Comment: arilia had a good suggestion, but the bigger problem is, we don't know what's wrong, since you're not providing an error message or any information as to how far into your code you're getting.  Try using `debug('here'); exit;` or something to determine where it's having issues.

Comment: arilia,thanks, but the error is occurring when running the save() method, not give me a specifc but wont save.

Comment: I found the problem was in using the Auth component. set to allow ('add');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, here is the codes:

Controller/CavasController.php:

```
<?php
class CanvasController extends AppController {
    public $name = 'Canvas';

    function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this -> layout = 'dialog';
        $this -> Auth -> allow();
        //$this -> layout = 'default-original';
    }

    public function index() {
        $this -> set('Canvas', $this -> Canvas -> find('all'));
    }

    public function setActiveCanvas($canvasId) {
        $this -> Session -> write('activeCanvas', $canvasId);
    }

    public function add() {
        if ($this -> request -> is('post')) {
            $this -> Canvas -> create();
            if ($this -> Canvas -> save($this -> request -> data)) {
                $this -> Session -> setFlash(__('The Canvas has been saved'));
                $this -> redirect('/');
            } else {

                $this -> Session -> setFlash(__('The Canvas could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
    }

    public function edit($id = null) {
        $this -> Canvas -> id = $id;
        if ($this -> request -> is('get')) {
            $this -> request -> data = $this -> Canvas -> read();
        } else if ($this -> Canvas -> save($this -> request -> data)) {
            $this -> Session -> setFlash('Canvas updated.');
            $this -> redirect('/');
        }
    }

    public function delete($id = null) {
        if (!$this -> request -> is('post')) {
            throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
        }

        $this -> Canvas -> id = $id;

        if (!$this -> Canvas -> exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid.'));
        }

        if ($this -> Canvas -> delete($id)) {
            $this -> Session -> setFlash('The Canvas with id: ' . $id . ' has been deleted.');
            $this -> redirect(array('controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'index'));
        }

        $this -> Session -> setFlash(__('Canvas was deleted.'));
        $this -> redirect(array('controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'index'));
    }

}
?>
```

Model/Canvas.php:

```
<?php
class Canvas extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Canvas';

    public $hasMany = array(
        'CanvasContents' => array(
            'classname' => 'CanvasContents', 
            'foreignKey' => 'canvas_id'
        )
    );

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Star' => array(
            'className'     => 'Stars',
            'foreignKey'    => 'stars_id'
        ),
        'User' => array(
            'className'     => 'Users',
            'foreignKey'    => 'users_id'
        ),
        'UserRole' => array(
            'className'     => 'UserRoles',
            'foreignkey'    => 'user_roles_id'
        )
    );

    public $validate = array(
        'name' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array(
                    'notEmpty'
                ),
                'message' => 'A name is required'
            )
        )
    );
}
?>
```

View/Canvas/add.ctp:

```
<?php echo $this -> Form -> create('Canvas',array('action'=>'add')); ?>
<fieldset>
    <?php   echo $this -> Form -> input('Canvas.name'); ?>
    <?php   echo $this -> Form -> input('Canvas.description'); ?>
</fieldset>
<?php   echo $this -> Form -> end(); ?>
```

MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sistema`.`canvas` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `description` TEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure what is wrong with your code. However, as a start you should try the following:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this -> request -> is('post')) {
        $this->Canvas->create(); // **** ADD This missing call ****
        if ($this -> Canvas -> save($this -> request -> data)) {
            $this -> Session -> setFlash(__('The Canvas has been saved'));
            $this -> redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this -> Session -> setFlash(__('The Canvas could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try it by adding  `$this->Canvas->create();` if you still have problem then the problem may be in table.. also check your dataabase table..